# What does the command "sudo apt-get install upgrade-system" do?

Tags: apt, package-management

I don't know what this command would actually do, or If I need the packages below?

Can't find any examples of `upgrade-system`

```
plutes@plutes-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ sudo apt-get install update
[sudo] password for plutes: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package update
plutes@plutes-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ sudo apt-get install upgrade-system 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  deborphan debsums dialog libfile-fnmatch-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed
  deborphan debsums dialog libfile-fnmatch-perl upgrade-system
0 to upgrade, 5 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 382 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,765 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
plutes@plutes-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ sudo apt-get update 
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
plutes@plutes-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
plutes@plutes-Lenovo-G50-30:~$
```

Comment: It's not `sudo apt-get install update` it's `sudo apt-get update`!

Comment: yeah I normally do, but some reason I accidentally typed install update, I didn't know there was a upgrade-system, but I am curious now.

Comment: And the `sudo apt-get install upgrade-system` sanitizes your system and upgrades it

Comment: Its not how to update from the command line, my question should be clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> upgrade-system  is  an  APT front-end that simplifies regular upgrading of Debian systems,
>              only requiring an administrator's intervention whenever updated packages  necessitate  the configuration of new features.

It has nothing to do with `apt-get update`, where `update` is a parameter to `apt-get`. You most probably do not need the package `upgrade-system`.

Comment: Thank you, Answered